# I'm having issues with leading zeros

Tags: java, if-statement, string-formatting

I'm attempting to get this to recognize the leading zeros in my program, and I thought using 'String.format("%03d", code);' would take care of it but I'm still not getting the expected result.

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
import java.io.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the shipment code :");
        int code = sc.nextInt();
        String.format("%03d", code);
        // fill the code
        if( code ==  111 ){
            System.out.println("All ways");
        }

        else if( code ==  110){
        System.out.println("Airway and Waterway");
        }

        else if( code ==  011){
        System.out.println("Waterway and Roadway");
        }
        else if( code ==  010){
        System.out.println("Waterway");
        }
        else if( code == 101){
        System.out.println("Airway and Roadway");
        }
        else if(code ==  001){
        System.out.println("Roadway");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not get the user to input a `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're discarding the formatted value. You need to store it in a variable and compare it as string:

```
String formatted = String.format("%03d", code);
if( formatted.equals("111") ){
    System.out.println("All ways");
}
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't seen formatted.equals when I was researching this. I appreciate the shared knowledge :).

Answer (score 3):

You're doing something wrong here.

`011`, `010`, `001` are **octal** numbers, as they start with a zero.
Also, using `String.format` is pointless here, as the resulting value is not used.
This might be why your `if` branches aren't taken into consideration.

```
final String formattedValue = String.format("%03d", code);
```

Now you can use `formattedValue` as a comparison value for your `if` statements.
Example

```
if ("111".equals(formattedValue)) { ... }
```

Note that maybe transforming the `int` into a `String` isn't necessary. But in case you insist on doing so, a good practice is to use a constant `String` as the operand which calls `equals(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `String.format("%03d", code)`, returns a **string**, and you are comparing to **integers** (octal integers, as LppEdd pointed out).

You should store the formatted string to a variable, e.g.

```
String formatted = String.format("%03d", code);
```

and then compare it to Strings in your if/else statements, like so:

```
if(formatted.equals("011")) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't format and remove any leading 0's in the condition and use switch

```
int code = sc.nextInt();
    // fill the code
switch(code) {
case 111:
    System.out.println("All ways");
    break;
case 110:
    System.out.println("Airway and Waterway");
    break;
case 11:
    System.out.println("Waterway and Roadway");
    break;
case 10:
    System.out.println("Waterway");
    break;
case 101:
    System.out.println("Airway and Roadway");
    break;
case 1:
    System.out.println("Roadway");
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("Unknown code " + code); 
    break;
}
```

Comment: I need each number to be three integers long, leading zeros are a requirement.

Comment: @NorHabboub But this only an internal representation of the codes and it can't make any difference how they are represented internally, "011" and 11 are equally unique. If it would be an requirement then you should force the user to input a 3 digit code and read it as a String (`sc.next()`)